# Closing database connection for rest service

Tags: node.js, node-mysql2

I am going to develop a REST service with Node Js, using mysql2 module and its pool API.
My question is:
**what is the way to deal with ending connections to databases a rest api service?**
A single client request may need to do multiple queries to database, so **my opinion** is that it's best to close the database connection after every request, not every query of course.
But I read that pools close connections automatically so **the other option** I have is not bothering about this problem at all.
What is your advice?

Comment: close and use a  connection pool.  That's what they are for

Comment: @OldProgrammer sorry I don't get you, you say close, I am asking when, when to close

Comment: close the connection after you are done with it in the REST call.